# How to find the coordinates of a second point of a segment?

Tags: geometry

please take a look at my drawing for better understanding of my problem:

[image]

What I know:

Coordinates of $P1, P2, P3$.  $P3$ lies on the segment $\overrightarrow{P1P2}$.
Angle $A$ between $\overrightarrow{P1P2}$ and $\overrightarrow{P3P4}$.
Length $L$ of $\overrightarrow{P3P4}$.

What I would like to know:

The coordinates of $P4$.

I would be grateful for any tips how to solve this problem.

**Edit**

Altough @Allijah's solution worked for the case that I've shown up, I was hoping for more general solution - the one which would work for all cases.

For example, here is another case for which the proposed solution will not work correctly:

[image]

Actually each case has two possible solutions: $P3$ and $P4$ (excluding angles $0$ and $180$ for which there is only one solution). Because I do not know if a point which I am searching lies above the known line or below it.

Comment: Step 1: throw away p1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For point $PK$ (where $K\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, let its coordinate be denoted as $(x_{PK},y_{PK})$.

Draw a line parallel to the x-axis that crosses point $P3$, and split the angle $A$ into $B$ (the angle between line $\overrightarrow{P3P2}$ and the horizontal line) and angle $C=A-B$ (the angle between line $\overrightarrow{P3P4}$ and the horizontal line).

As you know coordinates of $P2$ and $P3$, you can work out $B$ as this will be
$$B=\arctan\left(\frac{y_{P2}-y_{P3}}{x_{P2}-x_{P3}}\right)$$

Then you can calculate angle $C = A-B=A-\arctan\left(\frac{y_{P2}-y_{P3}}{x_{P2}-x_{P3}}\right)$.

Having found angle $C$, as you know both $L$ and the coordinates of $P3$, you can finally work out the coordinate of $P4$ in terms of the coordinates of $P3$ as follows:-
$$(x_{P4},y_{P4})=(x_{P3}+L\cos C,y_{P3}-L\sin C)$$

Comment: Could you extend your answer a little? Should I calculate the equation of the line $(y=ax+b) $ passing through the $P3$ basing on the knowledge that its $a $ is equal to the tangent of $C$ ? And then somehow use $L$ to calculate $P4$ ?

Comment: @Wodzu: As per your comment, I have extended the answer a little. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, will check this out tommorow on the real data.

Comment: I've checked your solution, but found some cases for which it does not work. Could you be so kind, and take a look at it?

Comment: I think that it should be $y_{P4} = (y_{P3}+L\sin C)$ (the plus sign not the minus).

Comment: @Wodzu My solution is quite specific to the first diagram posted in the question, and so will not work for the general case. As for why $y_{P4}=(y_{P3}-L\sin C)$, I had assumed that point $P4$ lies below $P3$.

Comment: Ok, I was able to change it to a general solution, thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @Wodzu: Well done on your general solution! And your welcome on the pointers.